# No bullet point between bullet points in revealjs Quarto

Tags: reveal.js, quarto

I would like to have no bullet points between bullet points in a revealjs presentation in Quarto. Here is some reproducible code:

```
---
title: "No bullet point between bullet points in Quarto"
format: revealjs
---

## Example slide

- Bullet point
No bullet point
- Bullet point
No bullet point
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see, the "No bullet point" are written after the "Bullet point" text, while I would like them to be separate without having a bullet point, something like how the code looks like. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to have list element without a bullet point between bullet points in `Quarto`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this give you the expected result? You need to add two white spaces such that pandoc knows that the bullet point for that line is finished.

```
---
title: "No bullet point between bullet points in Quarto"
format: revealjs
---

## Example slide

- Bullet point  <- two white spaces 
No bullet point
- Bullet point  <- two white spaces 
No bullet point
```

[image]

---

**Edit**: add css to use `.incremental`.

```
<style type="text/css">
li:nth-child(even)::marker {
  content: "";
}
</style>

## Next slide


:::{.incremental}
- Bullet point  
- No bullet point
- Bullet point  
- No bullet point

:::
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what it should look like, I was wondering do you know if it is possible to use `{.incremental}` for this, also for the non bullet points? When I use that, only the bullets are incremental?

Comment: yes, possible with css. I add an edit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is it possible to have incremental for the first part of your answer, with and without bullet points? Thanks!

Comment: My edit is also with and without bullet points? I had to change the approach since it is not really feasible with the inital answer - just inspect the elements and you will see why (it combines with and without in one element, i.e. not option to add different classes to it).